# What is the structure of Resolv.conf?

Tags: linux, apache, networking, dns

I've been searching far and wide and no one really explains what's supposed to go in this file from a simple point of view, what sort of options do I have?

At the moment I have purchased a VPS with a dedicated IP. I have set-up name-servers under the domain 888x7.com and assigned ns1.888x7.com (ns2 also) with the IP 109.169.46.109.

If you query the IP you get a test page, web server is working.

But if you try to access the page using 888x7.com or any other domain linked to both ns1 & ns2 you get the error:

```
ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED
```

currently my resolv.conf looks like this:

```
nameserver 109.169.46.109 888x7.com
nameserver 109.169.46.109 lolysoft.com
```

Is this correct? No where online (that I can find) does it describe this file in in detail.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your nameservers do not seem to know about the hosts on your domains:
`dig @109.169.46.109 ns1.888x7.com` returns `NO ANSWER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"man resolv.conf" will document what can go in this file.

You can also view it online here:
http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf

The nameserver directive should only contain the ip address of the nameserver, not it's hostname.

If you need to name some hosts that are not in DNS, you do that in the /etc/hosts file.

my hosts file on my VPS:

```
[nedwidek@sv ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
68.169.43.71      sv.lighthouseitc.com sv
```

This is there so that it can still resolve itself if the nameservers go down. Basically network name resolution goes first to the hosts file and then to DNS if the host isn't listed there. You can see what your server is set to do by looking at /etc/nsswitch.conf at the hosts directive (the attribute files means /etc/hosts and related files).

Now resolv.conf is to direct the system how to use the DNS system for network name resolution. My VPS's /etc/resolv.conf where I'm using one of Google's nameservers to resolve hosts.

```
[nedwidek@sv ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain lighthouseitc.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

The resolv.conf from my local machine (I run my own DNS server to serve my own private network at home):

```
[nedwidek@yule ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain ejnhome.net
search ejnhome.net
nameserver 192.168.101.1
```

The domain is just something I made up and hopefully no one ever uses (watch some joker decide to register it now). The search line basically sys that if I do "ping printer1" to treat it as if I did "ping printer1.ejnhome.net".

Ultimately I would try and find someone locally (friend or professional) who can help you. Attending a local Linux User Group (LUG) might help you find someone who is an enthusiastic amateur to give you a hand. Hopefully the real world examples help. I have 15 years of sys admin experience so sometimes I don't dumb it down far enough.

Comment: What exactly are mysecrethost mysecrethostalias suppose to be? 888x7.com www.888x7.com or something?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to confuse you. Your nameserver directives looked like you were trying to set up a host file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have misunderstood the purpose of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. This file is for configuring the name resolution client (stub resolver) on the local machine. It should list one or more recursive resolvers that are willing to provide you with name resolution service.

Configuring your authoritative nameservice is a completely different matter. If a domain like `888x7.com` is delegated to your service for authoritative nameservice, then you need to run an authoritative nameserver such as BIND on the service, and provision it with a zone file for `888x7.com` that contains the information you want to publish in DNS.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin with this.

Comment: Assuming your goal is to set up authoritative nameservice for `888x7.com` (which is not what you said in your question but it is nevertheless apparently what you want to do), you need to (1) change the IP address of either `ns1.888x7.com` or `ns2.888x7.com` in the registry because right now, they have the same IP address, and there is no point in listing 2 nameservers if they are actually the same server, (2) install BIND as I suggested (on both your primary and secondary nameserver), then (3) find a tutorial to provision BIND with a zone file for a new domain and follow it.